# Postgres - Pull results from multiple tables based on declared variable

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres.  I have 7 tables that have a common field (`AcctID`). I would like to pull results from each of the tables (without joining) based on the AcctID that I set (e.g. AcctID = '2352').

```
DO $$
Declare 
    AcctID := '2352';
BEGIN
    Select * from pbx.users where acct = AcctID;
    Select * from pbx.transactions where acct = AcctID;
    Select * from pbx.logs where acct = AcctID;
....
END;
$$;
```

I get error message that query has no destination.  Any recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*pull results*" - and do **what** with them?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is essentially telling you: "okay, so you want to pull these results, but then what?"

It is unclear to me why a join is inadequate for you, it would make things so much easier.

For this purpose, you can create a `stored procedure`, using a composite `out` parameter, such as the one proposed as an answer to this question: [Composite Array Type as OUTPUT parameter in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128807/composite-array-type-as-output-parameter-in-postgresql)

Yet, instead of that I really recommend the use of joins, such as

```
Select * 
from pbx.users
join pbx.transactions on pbx.users.acct = '2352' and pbx.users.acct = pbx.transactions.acct
join pbx.logs on pbx.transactions.acct = pbx.logs.acct;
```